# Menu icons - Joomla

Tags: html, css, joomla, icons

I'm creating a website in Joomla and I wanted to add icons to the menu, but they don't fit in what breaks the menu. What CSS code should I write so that the menu doesn't spill over? I tried to play with the size of li and a, but it doesn't work.

http://www.youseries.cba.pl

Comment: you did sp mega menu. each menus have a options available

Comment: @Constant you might like to ask your Joomla questions at [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.